# can't believe one's eyes or couldn't believe one's eyes

Tags: word-choice

> I  **can't believe my eyes when I see that my parents have bought me a new car!
>
> I *couldn't believe my eyes when I see that my parents have bought me a new car!

Which is better, can't or couldn't?
I prefer ''couldn't' as it is impossible for not believing one's own eyes?

Answer (score 1):

"Can't" is often used to express impossibility.  (In fact there are many cases where "couldn't" expresses a more tentative or conditional inability.)

"Can't believe my eyes" is the correct idiom (unless you are describing a past event).

> "(You've bought me a new car!)  I can't believe my eyes!"

I assume your sentence in the *historic present*, which is relatively rare in English:

> I **can't believe** my eyes when I **see** that my parents **have bought** me a new car.

(If you are describing the event to a friend shortly afterwards, while still able to see the car, and you still can't believe your eyes now, you could say "(I've just seen that) my parents have bought me a new car!  I can't believe my eyes!".

In the past tense it becomes:

> I **couldn't** believe my eyes when I **saw** that my parents **had bought** me a new car.

"Couldn't believe my eyes" usually refers to the past.  It could also refer to a potential future ("If that happened, I couldn't believe my eyes"), although in that case I'd prefer the periphrastic "I wouldn't be able to believe my eyes".